# Upgrade FFmpeg using Git

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to verify if my FFMpeg version is not updated.

Here's the output upon running this command: `ffmpeg -version`

```
ffmpeg version git-2013-04-05-9a8f1e7 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Apr  5 2013 18:38:36 with gcc 4.6 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libfaac --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libspeex --enable-librtmp --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree --enable-version3
```

I am not super familiar when FFmpeg is compiled and installed via Git.

I just followed the Ubuntu Compilation Guide by FFmpeg.

And how do I verify if it is not the latest?

PS: The remote is: `git://source.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.git`

Comment: looks like that is "not" the latest since it's a version from 2013-04-05.  I think you need to uninstall your current ffmpeg (or run `which -a ffmpeg`) possibly there are 2 installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It says pretty much everything in your image. Your FFmpeg is of Git build. Its version is `git-2013-04-05-9a8f1e7`. The rest all you can also read and understand yourself.

You can update yourself either from the [FFmpeg official download](http://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html) or [Git download](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg).

Also, FYI, currently the stable/major release is 2.1.

From FFmpeg documentation:

> Approximately every 3 months the FFmpeg project makes a new major release. Between major releases point releases will appear that add important bug fixes but no new features. Note that these releases are intended for distributors and system integrators.

Also for the current sub-version

> 2.1.3 was released on 2014-01-15. It is the latest stable FFmpeg release from the 2.1 release branch, which was cut from master on 2013-10-28

Comment: So if I pull from master branch, and the latest will be pulled. And after pulling, I just have to re-compile and build again? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The guide you mentioned, [How to Compile FFmpeg on Ubuntu](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/UbuntuCompilationGuide), has a dedicated section explaining how to update, but...

- The server hosting the guide is currently down. See the [Google Cache version](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3ahttp://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/UbuntuCompilationGuide) for now.
- This answer is for reference only, but you should follow the guide instead if possible since it may have updated since this answer was written (this is more for you readers in the future).
- I modified the instructions slightly to avoid issues with `yasm`.

---

## Updating FFmpeg

Development of FFmpeg is active and an occasional update can give you new features and bug fixes. First, remove (or move) the old files and then update the dependencies:

```
rm -rf ~/ffmpeg_build ~/bin/{ffmpeg,ffprobe,ffserver,x264}
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install autoconf automake build-essential git libass-dev libgpac-dev \
  libsdl1.2-dev libtheora-dev libtool libva-dev libvdpau-dev libvorbis-dev libx11-dev \
  libxext-dev libxfixes-dev pkg-config texi2html zlib1g-dev
export "PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin"
```

**Note**: Server users can omit: `libsdl1.2-dev libva-dev libvdpau-dev libx11-dev libxext-dev libxfixes-dev`.

### x264

```
cd ~/ffmpeg_sources/x264
make distclean
git pull
./configure --prefix="$HOME/ffmpeg_build" --bindir="$HOME/bin" --enable-static
make
make install
make distclean
```

### fdk-aac

```
cd ~/ffmpeg_sources/fdk-aac
make distclean
git pull
autoreconf -fiv
./configure --prefix="$HOME/ffmpeg_build" --disable-shared
make
make install
make distclean
```

### libvpx

```
cd ~/ffmpeg_sources/libvpx
make clean
git pull
./configure --prefix="$HOME/ffmpeg_build" --disable-examples
make
make install
make clean
```

### ffmpeg

```
cd ~/ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg
make distclean
git pull
PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib/pkgconfig"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH
./configure --prefix="$HOME/ffmpeg_build" \
  --extra-cflags="-I$HOME/ffmpeg_build/include" --extra-ldflags="-L$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib" \
  --bindir="$HOME/bin" --extra-libs="-ldl" --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac \
  --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx \
  --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree --enable-x11grab
make
make install
make distclean
hash -r
. ~/.profile
```